# move files to folder with same (Create folder with same name as of file and move) Java code

Tags: java

i would like to have a code which will have a option to browse a folder and once the folder is selected, star.star files should moved to folder creating a folder with same name as of files.

For example selected folder consists of files named a.txt, b.txt, c.txt folders named a, b, c should be created and respective files should be moved.

Comment: You should always provide an initial work about what you have done for example, any code or programming modules

Comment: So far, you've asked about three questions. You might want to narrow it down a little and prose some idea of what use tried

Comment: Have an idea? let's code it. So, do it if you are facing any problem than post a question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
for file in folder
    str = file.removeExtension()
    createDirectory(str)
    moveFile(file)
end
```

Just have a look at [Java API Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) and look for methods to provide these functionality.